# Move from 2005 Javascript spaghetti code to modular Javascript of 2013?

Tags: javascript, module

I have inherited a legacy JS multi page application and am contemplating the idea of migrating its code to modern day modular Javascript :

- implement loose coupling
- implement a modular system

Actually it seems a lot easier to start a new project using these techniques than to migrate an old style one.

What I have right now is stuff along the lines of

```
...
<a href="javascript:DoSomething('hey', 25);">Click this !</a>
...
```

and in a JS file a global function without any context, called DoSomething.

I read a lot about loose coupling and modular JS, but somehow I wonder how to actually implement stuff like my silly example, because it doesn't seem to have any context, and then that attaching all simple button/link actions through events and loose coupling makes it harder to read code and find out what a simple action command does.

How youd you actually implement this kind of thing, assuming there is a huge amount of such links and global functions everywhere ?

EDIT : I should have been more clearer, sorry.
Actually I can not use any JS-generated DOM technique such as Backbone views and so on, because all my HTML is generated server-side (it is mandatory in this app unfortunately) so the question remains as to how to efficienty come up with modules and such code, if most of what they do is respond to DOM events (on specific pre-defined elements generated server-side) and send data back to the server in form of page changes or AJAX calls.

For utility-like modules or other stuff decoupled from the DOM, it's quite clear how to implement modules, but for stuff tied to a static DOM that JS does not generate ?

Specifically, where and how to implement event handers, triggers changing DOM elements ? and so on.

Comment: have you heard about angularjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this in 2013 and it was a major undertaking.  RequireJS gives you the ability to separate your modules into separate files (if you want) where the dependencies are clearly laid out.  Backbone can give you some structure for breaking things into models and views (and your own control classes).  Underscore templating will let you make clean HTML templates that can be populated by a model's data.

The real answer is that you have to think like you would in a more traditional OOP language.  For instance a mediator pattern allows your modules to talk to each other while remaining decoupled.

If you have a **Click this** div on your page and a corresponding click listener in the javascript that would now live where the **Click this** div is in a simple template like:

```
<div id="myTarget">Click this</div>
```

While the main page might have something like:

```
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

Your Click This view might attach to #myApp and populate it with the contents of your simple template.
A backbone view which does this might look like:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#myApp",
    events: {
         "click #myTarget" : "handleClick"
    },
    handleClick : function(){
        // do something
    },
    render : function(){
        this.$el.html(myTemplate);
    }
});
```

Rinse and repeat for the various things you need to populate your page with.

Comment: Note that this backbone code is just there for flavor.  There are 10-20 other good practices that I would have in there too.

Comment: Thanks for the example Andy. I should have been more clearer maybe, see my edit in the question please

Comment: So backbone can still work with a static dom, you just don't implement render and you assign el to a specific CSS selector (like I did above).  In order to attach the event listeners in events you make a call (at which ever time you deem appropriate) to delegateEvents().  At that point it's really just a way of having a nice events package, router, and separated concerns.  When you say static I'm not sure if you mean that the dom can never ever change since you talk in the Edit about changing DOM elements.

Comment: Andy, sorry but I only know Backbone by name and from reading a bit of docs so I honestly didn't get half of your last comment, sorry. 
Static DOM means that any change is limited to toggling styles or classes on elements, maybe resizing and this kind of stuff, and replacing chunks of the dom by chunks coming from the server via AJAX. Why would someone want to use Backbone with static DOM not egenerated through templates ?

Comment: You are asking about how to modularize spaghetti JS code.  Backbone is not a templating engine (which I think is your impression).  It is a framework for keeping your code compartmentalized and to keep your domain logic out of the DOM.  If I understand correctly, your goal is to take the legacy code you inherited and refactor it into something clean, easy to work with, and sensibly designed.  The templating is a relatively small part of that task.  You should think about what in the code actually matters, where there is domain logic, and where there is presentation logic. Then create classes.

Comment: You're right, that's what I am set to do, and I assumed that backbone is an MVC framework that is mostly used with views, to be able to map models to views through controllers and to orchestrate all that music together, right ? So if I'm missing the views, I don't see how I can use it, but I'll do some research thanks. The idea is indeed to clean this up, but I thought about using modules instead of another layer of abstraction or lib like Backbone, but I'm no expertn hence my question

Comment: Well part of the reason I'm still commenting on this is that you aren't missing the views.  You have views and you will be manipulating them.  In backbone the views are actually the HTML and not what they label views, what they label views might be more of a presenter/controller than a view.  You have HTML which you must listen to events on, based on those events you must make business choices and possible twiddle classes in the HTML.  That seems like the sort of place where you will want separation of concerns.  Backbone takes a while to think in.  Backbone Views are controllers, HTML=view.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will investigate ! Happy holidays